# How to develop mdm agent in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm

I am implementing an MDM solution for windows phone 8. I am refering to the Enterprise Device

1. The management protocol said that windows phone 8 provided some configuration service provider called CSP,but i could not find any API about this in MSDN, so anybody knows where can i get the detailed usage about the CSP API in MSDN or other material?
2. Windows phone 8 enroll device through the process: System setting -> company apps -> add account -> input email address and password, and then enrolled. Can i avoid this process and develop the agent myself without going through the company apps to enroll the device?
3. Can anybody provide some material about how to develop mdm agent on windows phone 7?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MDM solution for WP8 is no small feat.

1. A good start for understanding CSP is the PDF document "Windows Phone 8 Enterprise Device Management Protocol" available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36831
2. The phone enrollment needs to be initiated by the user through Settings -> Company Apps. The phone goes through discovery process (SOAP) and then check-ins at regular intervals (SyncML). A regular WP8 app does not have access to any API to manage the phone like this; you cannot make a new/different client agent.
3. There is no MDM on the older WP7. I think you can do some basic stuff using ActiveSync (when the user configures an Exchange account) like require passwords with certain complexity, but I don't have any personal experience with that.

Comment: Do you know that how can i launch the Settings -> Company Apps from browser?

Comment: You can only launch certain built-in apps. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937.aspx. Company Apps is not on the list.

Comment: Hey can anyone post steps to enrol  wp8. I have gone through the pdf but steps are bit confusing. which service (url) server need to expose so that wp8 will poll at regular intervals.. I get even more confused as i read that pdf more